# write on an image in InteractiveViewer

Tags: flutter

I am looking for the easy way to edit an image,
or write on an image so as not to have to manage the zooms and scrolls I use,

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() =>runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}
class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
       home: Center(child:MyInteractiveViewer("Assets/img/carte.png"),),
   );
  }
}

class MyInteractiveViewer extends InteractiveViewer {
  MyInteractiveViewer(String carte):super(
      constrained :false,
      child: Image.asset(carte),
      minScale:0.10,
      maxScale:100.0){
    init();}

  void init(){
    print ("test"+child.toString());
  }

}
```

and is it possible to retrieve an obj or there is a paint to do something like

```
void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(300, 240), 300.2,new Paint());
  }
```

thank you for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

I answer my question
I did not find an answer but I propose a solution

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'dart:ui' as ui;
import 'package:flutter/services.dart' show rootBundle;
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() =>runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyAppState createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  String carte = "Assets/img/carte.png";
  ui.Image image;
  bool isImageloaded = false;
  TransformationController controller;
  void initState() {
    super.initState(); //init state
    init();// inii image load
  }

  Future <Null> init() async {
     Matrix4 matrix4 = Matrix4(
       1, 0, 0, 0,
        0, 1, 0, 0,
        0, 0, 1, 0,
        0, 0, 0, 1

    );
      controller = TransformationController(matrix4);

    final ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(carte);
    image = await loadImage(new Uint8List.view(data.buffer));
  }

  Future<ui.Image> loadImage(List<int> img) async {
    final Completer<ui.Image> completer = new Completer();
    ui.decodeImageFromList(img, (ui.Image img) {
      setState(() {
        isImageloaded = true;
      });
      return completer.complete(img);
    });
    return completer.future;
  }



  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: InteractiveViewer(
            transformationController: controller,//pas très utile mais bon
            minScale:0.1,
            maxScale:5,
            constrained :false,
            child: CustomPaint(
                size: Size(image.width.toDouble(), image.height.toDouble()),
                foregroundPainter: TestPainter(image),
              ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


class TestPainter extends CustomPainter {

  final ui.Image image;
  TestPainter(this.image);

  @override
  void paint(Canvas canvas, Size size) {
    final paint = Paint()
      ..color = Colors.blueGrey;
    canvas.drawImage(image, new Offset(0.0, 0.0), paint);
    canvas.drawCircle(Offset(400, 800), 50, paint);
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRepaint(CustomPainter oldDelegate) {
    return true;
  }
}
```